# Why the try-catch block is not able to handle the IllegalAccessException?

Tags: java, exception, illegalaccessexception

I am trying to catch an IllegalAccessException in the caller method. But it's not able to catch it. It's giving an error instead.

```
{
    static void fun()
    {
      try{
        System.out.println("Inside fun(). ");
        throw new IllegalAccessException("demo");
      }catch(IllegalAccessException e){
            throw e;
      }
    }
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        try
        {
            fun();
        }
        catch(IllegalAccessException e)
        {
            System.out.println("caught in main.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `static void fun() throws IllegalAccessException`

Comment: It's giving you *what* error instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `throws IllegalAccessException` the the methode signature, because IllegalAccessException is an checked expection and needs to be marked in the signature. Would you use an RuntimeExpection you do not need to added it in the signature.